# How to customize sort order of strings

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string

I am completely new to using string arrays. Consider this example:

I have the following values in a text box:

```
bufallo@2000
lice@20
cell@1
rat@150
cow@10000
```

When I sort them, they are sorted alphabetically, as in the list above.  However, I need them to sort in descending order using the integer value that follows the @ symbol.  So, for instance, I want the above list to be sorted like this:

```
cow@10000
bufallo@2000
rat@150
lice@20
cell@1
```

I have no idea on how to arrange them in descending order like that.

Comment: You will first need to explain the rules for sorting.

Comment: basically,the numbers following "string@integer" must be arrange in such a manner that the least valued integer must be at the last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to order by the numeric part of the string? No need for Regex.

You can use `String.Split` and `Enumerable.OrderByDescending`:

```
Dim number As Int32 = Int32.MinValue
Dim orderedLines = From line In TextBox1.Lines
                   Let parts = line.Split("@"c)
                   Let numericPart = parts.Last()
                   Let success = Int32.TryParse(numericPart, number)
                   Select LineInfo = New With {line, number}
                   Order By LineInfo.number Descending
                   Select LineInfo.line
' if you want to reassign it to the TextBox:
TextBox1.Lines = orderedLines.ToArray()
```

Comment: thanks for this sir,this really helped,where can i start learning about int32

Comment: `Int32` is just the type `Integer`. [`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) is what the name suggests: a method which tries to parse a string to an integer. Note that this is a `Linq` query. So you might want to learn that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397906.aspx

Answer (score 2):

While doing all your logic in a single LINQ expression can prove how clever you are :) sometimes the code is just easier to read and follow if you do it in a more verbose fashion.  So, if you don't want to use LINQ, you could create your own `IComparer` class which contains your custom sorting algorithm:

```
Public Class MyComparer
    Implements IComparer(Of String)

    Public Function Compare(ByVal x As String, ByVal y As String) As Integer Implements IComparer(Of String).Compare
        Dim xParts() As String = x.Split("@"c)
        Dim yParts() As String = y.Split("@"c)

        'Get the integer value (after the @ symbol) of each parameter
        Dim xValue As Integer = 0
        Dim yValue As Integer = 0
        If xParts.Length = 2 Then
            Integer.TryParse(xParts(1), xValue)
        End If
        If yParts.Length = 2 Then
            Integer.TryParse(yParts(1), yValue)
        End If

        'Compare y-to-x instead of x-to-y because we want descending order
        Return yValue.CompareTo(xValue)
    End Function
End Class
```

In this example, [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) is a standard .NET framework interface, which you are implementing in your `MyComparer` class.  The [Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh5ks3b3.aspx) method (as defined by `IComparer`) simply takes two parameters and compares them.  If `x` is less than `y` (i.e. `x` comes before `y` in the sort-order), the method will return a negative number (e.g. -1).  If `x` is greater than `y`, it will return a positive number (e.g. 1).  And if `x` and `y` are equal, then the method will return 0.

In this case, however, since all we want to do is use the standard integer sorting, we can just call [Integer.CompareTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2ky8xsk.aspx) which compares two integers and returns the negative, positive, or zero, as appropriate.

Then, when you call the `Array.Sort` method, you can give it one of your custom `IComparer` objects so that it uses your custom sorting algorithm instead of the default behavior:

```
Dim arrayToSort() As String = New String() {"bufallo@2000", "lice@20", "cell@1", "rat@150", "cow@10000"}
Array.Sort(arrayToSort, New MyComparer())
```

The [Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aw9s5t8f.aspx) method will use the `IComparer` object that you gave it to perform the sorting.  Each time it needs to compare two items in the array to see which should come first, it will call `MyComparer.Compare` and use the value returned by that method to determine the proper sorting.

You can re-use the same `MyComparer` class everywhere in your code that you need to sort items using that same algorithm, which is another benefit over the LINQ approach.  Implementing your own `IComparer` classes allows you to make all sorts of very powerful customize-able sort orders.

Comment: Fist of all,Thanks for the well elaborated ,Highly detailed answer.This is really helping me out,I cant thank you enough :)